# Question Lost Association after Migration

Tags: support, linked-accounts

This question:

[Error Starting Diaspora on Debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/326180/error-starting-diaspora-on-debian/336848#336848)

was originally asked by myself at a stackexchange site, and went through a number of migrations before ending up at serverfault.  I have openid associated accounts on each of the accounts, but the question lost association (the username is greyed out in the question) with my account when it got to serverfault.  I cannot accept the answer provided.

What is the right way to get the question associated?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure because your question has gone through so many migrations, but it *should* just be a case of making sure you've got the exact same OpenID credentials on both sites.

However, all bets are off when it's gone through that many migrations, perhaps when it migrates as anonymous it loses that data on subsequent migrations.

Your best bet is to use the email address at the bottom of the page ("contact us") and ask them to take a look at it.

Comment: If a Post migrates to a site where you do not have the same OpenID associated it will be placed in a Ghost account. Any migrations from that Ghost account will remain in Ghost Accounts. Posts by Ghost Accounts can be claimed before migration, `if (claimed) goto 1`. If a Post by Ghost Account is migrated it will remain as a Ghost Account and likely can not be claimed (automatically) until all intermediate migrated posts are also claimed (pretty sure post will only dereference one migration level).